# Is there a Brazilian mail forwarding service?

Tags: brazilian-citizens

I have moved from Brazil to the UK, but I still need to receive mail from Brazilian senders who are not willing to send it abroad (mainly government stuff). So, I'm looking for a mail forwarding service, which would give me a Brazilian address and would forward everything I receive in that address to my real address in the UK.

I have found several services like this, but all of them redirect from the US to other countries. I am looking for a Brazilian alternative.

Comment: You may have luck searching for Escritório Virtual no Brasil (virtual office in Brazil).

Answer (score 1):

Many of the UPS shops have mail service. This one may help.  There are other UPS shops there, and everywhere.

http://www.ups.com/content/br/en/contact/